# hibernate JPA -fetches duplicate records when child entity's field is used for sort/order the output records using queryDSL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

When I use queryDSL's orderBy method to sort the records, it is giving duplicate records if I use child entity's field in the orderBy method.

For example, consider the below entities:

Student entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

  @Id
  @Column(unique = true)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
  private List<Book> books;

  @Column
  private String name;
```

Book entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Books {


  @Id
  @Column(unique = true)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "studentId")
  private Student student;

  @Column
  private String author;
```

Code to fetch records:

```
 QStudent qStudent = QStudent.student;
    JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(getEntityManager());
    query.from(qStudent).orderBy(qStudent.books.any().author.asc());
    if (!query.list(qStudent).isEmpty()) {
      return query.list(qStudent);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

In the above code, I am ordering the records based on "author" which is a field of child(book) entity. In this case I am getting duplicate records (getting 4 records instead of 2). But, when I do orderBy with parent(student) entity field like below, I get exactly 2 records and no duplicates.

```
query.from(qStudent).orderBy(qStudent.name.asc());
```

Can anyone please let me know how to do ordering using queryDSL by using child entity field without duplicates? Thank you in advance.